# Print max value in row and column name R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, return

I'm trying to create a function that takes in a data frame and a value from the first column of the data frame. Let's call the value from the first column of the data frame "value1". This means the function should be in a form

```
Function <- function (data, value1)
```

If "value1" is found from the data, it should return "value1", the maximum value of the row the "value1" is in, and the column name of the maximum value.

If "value1" is not found, it should return "Check value".

What I've done so far:

```
value1 <- function(data) {
data[1]
}

Function <- function (data, "value1") {
if(any(value1 %in% data[[1]])) {
maxcol <- which.max(data[value1,])
print(paste(value1, data[maxcol,], data[maxcol, value1]))
} else {
print("Check value")}
}
```

I created "value1" separately because I didn't know how to do it otherwise.

My problem is that the function doesn't print the correct things when "value1" is found.

Comment: Can you post reproducible data using dput()? That makes it a lot easier to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(indexValue = sample(letters, size=5),
                  col2 = runif(n=5),
                  col3 = runif(n=5))
df

  indexValue      col2       col3
1          n 0.2016819 0.06178627
2          y 0.8983897 0.20597457
3          d 0.9446753 0.17655675
4          g 0.6607978 0.68702285
5          a 0.6291140 0.38410372

lookup <- function(data, value1){
     rowFound <- min(which(data$indexValue==value1))
     if(! rowFound <= length(data)){"Check value"} else {
       paste0(names(data)[rowFound+1], ": ", apply(data[rowFound, c('col2', 'col3')], 1, max))}}

lookup(df, 'n')
[1] "col2: 0.201681931037456"
> lookup(df, 'c')
[1] "Check value"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I fail to understand the min(which(data$indexValue==value1)) part. Since I would like value1 to be a value from the first column, isn't data$indexValue==value1 just stating the obvious? I might be wrong but is there something I should change in my value1 now for this code to work? I think my value1 is taking the whole first column now instead of a value from it....

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(A=c(3,2,1,4,5),B=c(1,6,3,8,4),C=c(2,1,4,8,9))

  A B C
1 3 1 2
2 2 6 1
3 1 3 4
4 4 8 8
5 5 4 9

foo1 <- function(Column,Value){
  pos <- which(Column[-1] == Value)
  if(length(pos)==0){result <- "Check value"}
  else {result <- paste(Value,max(Column[-1],na.rm = TRUE),
                        Column[1],sep=",")}
  result
}

# check after 2

apply(rbind(colnames(df),df),2,function(x) foo1(x,2))

       A             B             C 
      "2,5,A" "Check value"       "2,9,C"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I need the function to take in a data frame. Would it work that way?

Comment: Hi, Could you please provide a example for the output you wish?